# UV Mapping to Imported svg Problems

Tags: texturing, uv, svg

I'm having a very difficult time properly texturing a tile floor mesh that I created from an imported SVG file.

There are several points in the mesh where there appears to be a seam where there shouldn't be one. I've created seams along the perimeter of the mesh and it appears correct in the image/uv editor so I don't know why this is happening. I'm relatively new to Blender so I'm hoping there is an easy solution I'm not aware of.

When the .svg was imported the mesh was a complete disaster so I deleted all edges aside from the perimeter and created quads manually by selecting 4 vertices and making a face "F". But for some reason selecting the edge loops of the perimeter only selects a small portion of the edges. Not sure if that is related to my problem.

[image: Texture Mismapped]

Comment: What does your UV map look like?

Comment: "*When the .svg was imported the mesh was a complete disaster*" SVGs import as bezier curve objects, you should have left it as one. All you had to do was use *Generated* or *Object* texture coordinates. You now have a hard to edit mesh with NGons and bad topology. Don't needlessly convert to mesh unless strictly needed to.

Comment: Thanks guys! @cegaton, this method worked great, I assumed if I had a defined seam it would work by just using the "unwrap" method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unwrap UVs again.

Select the top faces, got to top orthogonal view, press <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap and select **project form view**.